# Append leading zero in numeric varchar field in QueryContext Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot

I am working on a spring project in which sorting to be applied in ascending or descending order. The column type is varchar. This field will contain numeric values decimal or numeric both. It may contain combination of the alphabet and number (There may be fewer chances of adding such values). As this is the requirement by the client so I can not change the data type of column.

Let's say values for myNum fields are :

- 2.12
- 0.11
- 0.45
- 1.7
- A12
- 4.80
- B34
- 0.56

After the sort, it should show number at up then alphabet at down:

- 0.11
- 0.45
- 0.56
- 1.7
- 2.12
- 4.80
- A12
- B34

The code to create the query to sort is :

```
 queryContext.getSorts().forEach((s) -> {
                if (orderByClauses.length() > 0) {
                    orderByClauses.append(", ");
                }
                if (s.getColumnName().equalsIgnoreCase("myNum")) {                    
                    orderByClauses.append("regexp_substr(myNum, '^\\D*') nulls first, to_number(regexp_substr(myNum, '\\d+\\.?\\d*'))");                   
                } else {
                    orderByClauses.append(s.getColumnName() + " ");   
                }
                orderByClauses.append(s.getDirection().toString());
            });
```

The code working fine for the above example, but the case is that when I add .34 or .56 (without leading zero before the decimal) the sorting is not working correctly.

How can I append zero to regexp_substr to get the correct result?

Comment: `regexp_replace(str, '^\.', '0.')` ?

Comment: @PonderStibbons not working

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle 12.2 or higher then you can take advantage of the `TO_NUMBER` function with `ON CONVERSION ERROR` clause in `ORDER BY` clause as follows:

```
TO_NUMBER(myNum DEFAULT 999999999 ON CONVERSION ERROR), MYNUM  -- Your orderByClauses
```

**--Update**

For a lower version of the oracle, use regexp_like as following

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(myNum, '^[\.|[:digit:]]+$') THEN 1 ELSE 2 END 
,MYNUM -- Your orderByClauses
```

Cheers!!

Comment: We are using Oracle 12c and the above clause is not working with my to_number.

Comment: Can please you check your solution here : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/43875/1 and let me know.